# Can you insert into sorted list with time O(1)?

Tags: time-complexity, arrays

Wondering if this was possible. If I have a sorted list, can I find the right spot for an integer and insert it, all in O(1) time? The only way I can think to do this is via having a MASSIVE hashmap with one slot for each possible integer. 2 billion different integers * 4 bytes per integer = 8 gigabytes....but it'd technically work. There has to be a better way to do this though, right?

Comment: Your title only says "sorted list" but to do it O(1) requires "sorted list of (bounded) integers" e.g. 32b/64b/etc. You can't do this for unbounded integers (or floats, strings, arbitrary objects).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a solution for bounded integers, 32-bit for example. If so, any sorted dictionary whose complexity depends on the key length only will do what you want. Two examples are [binary trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and [van Emde Boas tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree).

Answer (score 1):

One way to convince yourself it is not possible is to consider what it would enable. Assume there exists an O(1) algorithm for insertion into an unbounded sorted array, CONST_INSERT. Then we can define a O(n) sorting algorithm as follows:

- Let $L$ be an empty list $()$ and $U = (u_1, u_2, \ldots u_n)$ be an unsorted list.
- Iterate over $i: 1 \rightarrow n$, inserting $u_i$ into $L$ using CONST_INSERT

This produces a sorted array, since at the end of every iteration $i$, $L$ will be exactly a sorted list of $(u_1 \ldots u_i)$. And it will have a runtime of O(n).

From a practical perspective, if an O(n) sorting algorithm existed it would be very useful, so you'd likely know about it. From a theory perspective, [resources like this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eavrim/451f11/lectures/lect0913.pdf)
might help you convince yourself that no such sorting algorithm could exist.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that sorting is done for 4-byte integers. Comparison-based sorting lower bound doesn’t apply here.

Comment: That's a good point, and it looks like your answer is a good overview of the things applicable to the bounded case.

Answer (score 0):

One thing before I explain: `HashMap` doesn't use an array that big, it uses *chaining*, which is another concept you'll have to look up. And if you're talking about creating an array size 2 billion, that still won't work because you still have to scan the 2 billion entries in the array. Ok, technically that's O(1), but only because O(2 billion) is counted as O(1).

I actually wondered about this for a long time. If you think about it, there is no possible way even with the `HashMap`. Before I get into why `HashMap` doesn't work, if you don't use a `HashMap`, you'll have to scan the whole size that you have to insert. Now to the `HashMap` part, after inserting you're number, you'll have to update ***every*** entry after that. And if you don't, you'll get an O(1) insertion *once*, but after that you'll get wrong insertions.